# registering event to newly added selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding and removing items from a ul. However, I cannot remove items that were just added. I am assuming I need to register the event when the item is added. How to do this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are registering an event handler for every `li` item in your `ul`, use the [.live()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) function.  This will register the same handler for every new `li` item that shows up on the page.

For example,

```
$("li").live("click", function(){
      $(this).remove();
    });
```

If this doesn't answer your question, could you edit it to be a bit more clear about what you're trying to do?